# How to add badge on push notification using brozot/Laravel-FCM

Tags: php, ios, laravel, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to add badge on push notification using brozot/Laravel-FCM ?

I'm sending notifications correctly to iOS devices, but I would like to know how can I send badge information with the notification?

I tried this code but not working

````
            $optionBuilder = new OptionsBuilder();
            $optionBuilder->setTimeToLive(43200);
            
            $notificationBuilder = new PayloadNotificationBuilder();
            
            $notificationBuilder->setBody($payload['notificationmessage'])
                                    ->setImage($payload['imageurl'])
                                    ->setBadge($payload['badgecount']);
            
            $dataBuilder = new PayloadDataBuilder();
            $dataBuilder->addData(['device_data' => $payload]);

            $option = $optionBuilder->build();
            $notification = $notificationBuilder->build();
            $data = $dataBuilder->build();
            
            $downstreamResponse = FCM::sendTo($value->device_token, $option, $notification, $data);```

running the about code is throwing this error ---->

```[2020-11-02 04:49:28] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function setBadge() on string in /var/www/html/app/Http/Controllers/api/v1/NotificationsController.php:221```
````

Comment: please read this doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support you can pass `badge Optional, string`

Comment: Yes, added that in the code. it supposed to take String as an input but getting "Call to a member function setBadge() on string" error